# How do I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to an ASMX webservice I have created in VB?

Tags: ajax, vb.net, asmx

I have a very simple ASMX page...

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

<WebService(Namespace:="http://localhost/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ScriptService()> _
Public Class JSWSGuessWeddingsByDay
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
    Public Function HowManyPeopleAreGettingMarriedToday() As Integer

        Dim weddingCount As New Controller.Member.MemberDal

        Return weddingCount.GuessWeddingsByDay(Nothing)

    End Function
End Class
```

How do I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the response headers so that the webservice can be consumed by multiple websites using AJAX?

Comment: BTW, it's not a "page" of any kind.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding this before your return statement?:

`Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")`

Comment: It's a webservice, you have to use Context.Response.AppendHeader("..")